# Создание БД на SD карте

Tags: android, sqlite

Я пытаюсь создать БД на SD-карте, но когда я вызываю getReadableDatabase (), я получаю:

```
Failed to open database '/storage/sdcard1/xAPP/inventory.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database.
```

Если я помещу базу данных на SD-карту вручную, появятся следующие ошибки:

```
Failed to open database '/storage/sdcard1/xAPP/inventory.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode
```

Я подчеркиваю, что речь идет не о внешнем хранилище, а о съемном хранилище (SD-карта)! Если я использую Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (), все работает хорошо!

Как решить обозначенную проблему?

Comment: Как вы этот путь получаете `/storage/sdcard1/xAPP/inventory.db`? Или он у вас просто в коде вбит? `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` разрешение запрашиваете?

Comment: Путь получаю, как описано здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/254813/ Разрешение конечно же есть, я же написал, что с Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () все хорошо.

Comment: база данных не может работать напрямую с SD-карты. Ее надо скопировать в внутрений каталог приложения: data/data/<package_name>/databases/

Comment: @pavlofff, Почему не может? Есть официальная инфа?

Comment: Ну точнее, вы можете переписать методы класса SQLiteOpenHelper чтобы был доступ к базе на SD-карте (создать свой класс-наследник). Сам класс SQLiteOpenHelper работает только с внутренней памятью приложения.

Comment: @pavlofff, как именно переписать?

Comment: `getReadableDatabase()` для определения пути, где лежит БД вызывает метод `Context.getDatabasePath()`.

Соответственно вам надо перегрузить указанный метод, чтобы он показывал на нужный вам путь.

Comment: @Barmaley, если это так, то почему через Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () работает? Пути разные.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir(null): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files   context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME): /data/data/com.xxx.xxx/databases/inventory.db

Comment: Возможно, у вас банально путь кривой, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` вам верно путь строит, вот и работает.

Comment: И еще, кто вам сказал, что SD-карта не `external storage`? Вот тут об этом явно написано: `a removable storage medium such as a micro SD card (external storage)` https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Путь не кривой точно. SD - это removable storage. Внешняя память может быть removable и нет.